# How to obtain an enumerable over the lines of standard input in C#?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm learning Linq in C# and built a little word frequency script:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

class WordCounter
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Regex wordRegex = new Regex(@"[\p{L}']+");
        File.ReadLines("../test/wordcount_input")
            .SelectMany(line => wordRegex.Matches(line).Cast<Match>())
            .Select(x => x.Value.ToLower())
            .GroupBy(x => x)
            .OrderBy(x => x.Key)
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(p => Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", p.Key, p.Count()));
    }
}
```

This works but I want to replace the hardcoded file name with standard input. Unfortunately I don't know how to do this. I have tried

```
Console.In.ReadLines()
```

but that method does not exist on `Console.In`. How can I use standard input in place of the hardcoded filename?

(Note: I have written this script without Linq earlier, so the question isn't whether Linq is appropriate for this problem. I'm simply trying to learn Linq and thought this would make a good experiment.)

Comment: How many lines should be obtained before you process?

Comment: Not sure you can do this sort of thing directly with console. You could simulate it with Reactive Extensions or build your own enumerable and loop on that.

Comment: Try soemthing like following, although there is an issue that standardinput has to be closed before method completes :             Stream stream  = Console.OpenStandardInput();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            reader.ReadToEnd().Split(new char {'\n', '\r'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries()).SelectMany(....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a method like this:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> GetConsoleInputLines()
{
    while (Console.In.Peek() >= 0)
        yield return Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The problem with `Console.ReadLine()` is that it blocks until a complete line has been provided. The implementation above stops iterating when there are no more lines.

If you leave out the `while` condition, you can iterate this `IEnumerable` as long as the user inputs new lines, but any `foreach` on this enumerator will block forever.

Comment: Well I do plan on using command line redirection (or command line pipes) in which case the blocking is not a concern. Perfectly fine if it blocks "forever" if run on the console without redirection. It's very interesting that in C# standard input seems to be treated differently. In Python I can use `sys.stdin` and heck even in Java using `new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).lines()` gives me the stream! I can't believe Java makes something easy that C# would require extra work for. So, do you know if there is something like `Console.In.Lines()`?

Comment: @RayToal No, I don't know. `Console.In` is a [`TextReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textreader(v=vs.110).aspx) and that only provides a `ReadLine()` method.